# Quasi-random sampling in Julia

Tags: julia

Where can I find a Julia package to generate low-discrepancy sequences of numbers? I searched the internet and only find Sobol.jl package. I want more options like hammersley and halton sequences.

Comment: http://surrogates.juliadiffeq.org/dev/samples/

Comment: Via pkg.julialang.org, I found the following packages by your keywords: https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/QuasiMonteCarlo.jl, https://github.com/tobydriscoll/HaltonSequences.jl.